# Why is data loading to voltdb slow?

Tags: database, load, loading, voltdb

What is the fastest way to load data into voltdb. I'm using the recommended command: csvloader in the form:

```
$ csvloader helloworld -f languages.csv
```

but the loading time is very long. Why is it slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam, Did you have the tables helloworld partitioned in your schema?

Answer (score 1):

VoltDB main idea: the goal of **partitioning** is to distribute both the data and the processing. I did partitioning and managed to receive a reasonable loading time.

http://docs.voltdb.com/tutorial/Part3.php says:
Comparing the load times before and after adding partitioning shows that adding partitioning increases the ingestion rate for the Towns table from approximately 5,000 to 16,000 TPS — more than three times as fast! This performance improvement is a result of parallelizing the stored procedure calls across eight sites (partitions) per host. Increasing the number of sites per host can provide additional improvements, assuming the server has the core processors necessary to manage the additional threads.